# c# winforms не работает scroll колесо прокрутки в контролах

Tags: c#, winforms, прокрутка

на форме есть Panel, autoscroll=true, в нее добавляю много картинок например, появляется vscrollbar, но колесо упорно не хочет скроллить элемент. Попробовал flowLayoutPanel, то же самое. Это что, теперь надо писать обработчик на колесо?

Comment: А фокус на панеле установлен?

Comment: спасибо, вроде решил, насильственной установкой фокуса, т.к. кликом фокус не получал